# Destination info: Left/right side flutter maps

Tags: android, flutter, geolocation, maps, latitude-longitude

after reached the destination, Is there any way to get whether the destination is on left/right side respective to my current position. if so please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can compare source and destination longitudes. 
[Here shows how you can work with geolocator.](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator#-readme-tab-)

Comment: hi, thanx for the quick reply. it would be great if you can you please provide any link or logic. i searched through but i wat unable find any solution